# Nintegrate do not evaluate the integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages

Here is the code

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
fun = Exp[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]/\[Lambda]]*z*(a - z)*x*(b - x)*   y*(c - y)
lp = Laplacian[fun, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"] // FullSimplify
ft[\[Lambda]_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[lp, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}] // Timing
NMinimize[ft[\[Lambda]], \[Lambda]]
```

And ı  get errors.Mathematica do not integrate my equations.

Comment: Perhaps if you look at the errors they may give a hint as to what has gone wrong? Which line does not work? Is lp defined correctly?

Answer (score 2):

After correcting some errors, `NMinimize` was taking too long for me to wait for it. But you can generate a plot a $ft(\lambda)$ vs $\lambda$ to get an idea where the minimum is. Also at $\lambda=0$ your integral blow up (singularity) so added a check to by pass $\lambda=0$. This function seems to go to negative $\infty$ for small $\lambda$. Actually if you make  $\lambda$ too small. `NIntegrate` starts to complain:

```
 value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand
```

Here is the code.

```
ClearAll[x,y,z,lam,lp]
a=1;
b=1;
c=1;
fun=Exp[-Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]/lam]*z*(a-z)*x*(b-x)*y*(c-y);
lp[lam_?NumericQ]=Laplacian[fun,{x,y,z},"Cartesian"]//FullSimplify;
ft[lam_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[lp[lam],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},{z,0,1}];

(*make data and skip lam=0 *)
data=Table[If[lam!=0,{lam,ft[lam]},Nothing],{lam,-2,2,.05}];

ListLinePlot[data,AxesLabel->{"lambda","ft[lambda]"},ImageSize->400,PlotStyle->Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you look at the data, you'll see it goes to very large value in the negative direction as $\lambda$ gets close to zero.  Here is part of `data` from above near zero

```
...{-0.12, -5554.88}, {-0.11, -15999.9}, {-0.1, -57745.4}, 
   {-0.09, -282540.}, {-0.08, -2.11232*10^6}, {-0.07, -2.91947*10^7}, 
   {-0.06, -1.02921*10^9}, {-0.05, -1.66462*10^11}, {-0.04, -4.0507*10^14}, 
   {-0.03, -2.43063*10^20}, {-0.02, -1.68737*10^32}, 
   {-0.01,-4.40059*10^68}, {0.01, -8.52707*10^-8}, {0.02, -1.29092*10^-6}..
```

So the minimum is at $\lambda=0$ ?

Comment: Yes,it seems zero,thank you for your help.You have clarified the situation.